# DocuSign API explorer - does not recognize tabs for Signature

Tags: api, docusignapi, explorer

I'm using the DocuSign API explorer to test the use of tabs for signature. I've created a Word document with a placeholder called /InternSignatureAnchor/ [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBnwZ.png)

And the JSON request payload looks like this:

```
{
  "documents": [
    {
      "documentBase64": "<Base64BytesHere>",
      "documentId": "123456",
      "fileExtension": "DOCX",
      "name": "Freelance Contract"
    }
  ],
  "emailSubject": "Please Sign Contracts 3",
  "recipients": {
    "signers": [
      {
        "email": "dummy_email123@mmmm.mmm",
        "name": "Dummy Recipient 1",
        "recipientId": "1",
        "roleName": "Internal Signatory",
        "routingOrder": "1",
        "tabs": {
          "signHereTabs": [
            {
              "documentId": "123456",
              "pageNumber": "1",
              "tabLabel": "/InternSignatureAnchor/",
              "xPosition": "0",
              "yPosition": "36"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "email": "dummy_email321@mmmmm.mmm",
        "name": "Dummy recipient 2",
        "recipientId": "2",
        "roleName": "External Signatory",
        "routingOrder": "2"
      }
    ]
  },
  "status": "sent"
}
```

When the signatory opens the document to sign, the "Sign" [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrKCV.png)

is not placed at the placeholder /InternSignatureAnchor/. When I use the Autoplace feature in DocuSign itself, it does work.

Anyone an idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! PLEASE check (accept) the best answer to each of your questions. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "tagLabel" will just add a label to a tag. To use AutoTagging you'd need to use a json like below:

```json
"tabs": {
    "signHereTabs": [{
        "anchorString": "Please Sign Here",
        "anchorXOffset": "1",
        "anchorYOffset": "0",
        "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "false",
        "anchorUnits": "inches"
    }]
}
```

I believe API explorer does not show the fields for auto tagging currently - so you'd need to perhaps use Postman to play around with this feature.

Comment: Ah, thanks a lot - I'll use postman for testing.